# 99 ford escort zx2 turbo jumped timing belt

Tags: escort

So I'm looking into this 1999 Ford Escort zx2 turbo as kind of a fun little car to have. The guy only wants 600 for it. He said it jumped the timing at the dyno and the pistons hit the exhaust valves and bent them. Hes saying that the forged pistons are fine and the only thing the car needs is exhaust valves. I'm pretty handy when it comes to working on vehicles and I was wondering if this would be something I could fix my self? If not I'm curious as to what it would cost to have a mechanic fix it? Thanks

Comment: My advice is DO NOT buy a vehicle that has a known powertrain problem unless you are ready to rebuild the engine or swap for a new one. Valve work can be tricky, especially if the timing of the cams is currently wrong. Swapping another engine in would be easier and less expensive.

Comment: It's a big job, that's for sure. And I imagine a tough one for a person without experience in this area. Besides, you can't be sure that only the exhaust valves were damaged.